# Sobject tree parent field update

Tags: rest-api, api, integration, force, sobject-tree

I have a child record called Order, Account is Parent of Order. I am trying to insert a Order via sObject tree and at the same time I am trying to update its parent field but it throwing an error, any pointers?

```
Invalid status code: 400, response body: [{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of <unknown> from FIELD_NAME value records or request may be missing a required field","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]
```

SObject structure I am passing

```
[{
    Ascent4Ecomm__Ecomm_Order_ID__c     : payload.ns0#order.ns0#"original-order-no",
    PBSI__Tax_on_Shipping__c            : payload.ns0#order.ns0#totals.ns0#"shipping-total".ns0#"tax",
    attributes: {
        "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c", //Child record
        "referenceId": "SO"
    },
    
       PBSI__Customer__r: { //Parent record
        records: [
                    {
                            "attributes": {"type": "Account","referenceId": "newsLetterRegistration"},
                            Marketing_Opt_in__r : true  //Field to update on Parent Account
                    }
                ]           
    },

    PBSI__Customer__c: (payload.ns0#order.ns0#"custom-attributes".*ns0#"custom-attribute" filter(item) -> (item.@"attribute-id" == "sscAccountid")) [0]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

sObject Composite Tree **cannot** update records, only create **new** records. What you're looking for is the [Composite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite.htm) request, instead. You'll want to read the documentation carefully, but here's the example from the documentation:

```
{
"compositeRequest" : [{
  "method" : "POST",
  "url" : "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Account",
  "referenceId" : "refAccount",
  "body" : { "Name" : "Sample Account" }
  },{
  "method" : "POST",
  "url" : "/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/Contact",
  "referenceId" : "refContact",
  "body" : { 
    "LastName" : "Sample Contact",
    "AccountId" : "@{refAccount.id}"
    }
  }]
}
```